# Does Query cache on MySQL automatically reset after a while? Some results cache for a bit but then are resetting the next day

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I do a query like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM graphql.cases 
where parties = 'Bondelmonte v Bondelmonte' 
LIMIT 0, 1000
```

It takes 2 seconds. Then I repeat it, taking 0.2 seconds, showing me that caching is working.

But the next day I repeat this same thing, and again, it takes 2 seconds at first and then 0.2 seconds after that.

Didn't I already cache the query the first time, a day ago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various situations that may cause the results of a query to be flushed out of the cache, for example:

- data might have been modified
- you might have run a statement whose text is slighly different to the one that was cached (lower/upper case, line breaks, ...)
- the cache might have reached one of its size limits (memory, queries count, blocks, ...) and decided to evict your specific query
- cache fragmentation got high and forced the cache to prune your query even while some memory was still available
- and so on...

Bottom line: even with proper fine-tuning, queries do not stay cached forever; time to time, MySQL will need to re-execute the query and cache it again, and this is what you are seeing.

For your reference, here are a few quotes from [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html):

> Queries must be exactly the same (byte for byte) to be seen as identical. In addition, query strings that are identical may be treated as different for other reasons. Queries that use different databases, different protocol versions, or different default character sets are considered different queries and are cached separately.
>
> [...]
>
> If a table changes, all cached queries that use the table become invalid and are removed from the cache. This includes queries that use `MERGE` tables that map to the changed table. A table can be changed by many types of statements, such as `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `TRUNCATE TABLE`, `ALTER TABLE`, `DROP TABLE`, or `DROP DATABASE`.
>
> [...]
>
> If you have a lot of queries with small results, the default block size may lead to memory fragmentation, as indicated by a large number of free blocks. Fragmentation can force the query cache to prune (delete) queries from the cache due to lack of memory